# How to get a li with no class underneath a div tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to pull line and over under data for games from ESPN. To do this I need to pull a list item underneath a div tag.I can successfully get the over/under data because it's clear to me what the tag is, but the list item for the line doesn't seem to have a clear tag. Essentially I would be wanting to pull out "Line: IOWA -3.5" from this specific URL.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
page = requests.get('https://www.espn.com/college- football/game/_/gameId/401012863')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#Get over/under
game_ou = soup.find('li',class_='ou')
game_ou2 = game_ou.contents[0]
game_ou3=game_ou2.strip()

#Get Line
game_line = soup.find('div',class_='odds-details')
print(game_line)
```

Comment: Can you just get the `li` by sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in the parent class (with [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) and child `li` [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors)) then you can retrieve both li in a list and index in or just use select_one to retrieve the first

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.espn.com/college-football/game/_/gameId/401012863')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
lis = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('.odds-details li')]
print(lis[0])
print(lis[1])
print(soup.select_one('.odds-details li').text)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `find('li')` after find the div element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.espn.com/college-football/game/_/gameId/401012863')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find("div",class_="odds-details").find('li').text)
print(soup.find("div",class_="odds-details").find('li',class_='ou').text.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Line: IOWA -3.5
Over/Under: 47
```